# Whats the equivalent of winId to qml?

Tags: qt, c++11, qml

I want to get the value of a label id in qml and send this id to a cpp function, I want to do as the same as:

This is one example in QtGui

```
QLabel *painel;
painel->winId();
```

and get the value like 69206100, I want to do this in qml, but I dont know how.

Comment: And what exactly is that and how do you plan to use it? Why would plain `QWidget *` not suffice?